# Bookshelf with cutout

Tags: design, strength

I've built a bookshelf that is basically just glued wood with notches cut in:

[image: Closeup]

With the vertical struts 50cm apart, this is ideal for just about anything: it nicely fits 40cm Euroboxes and 19 inch electronics.

Now I'd like to do the same again, but 60cm deep, and with a builtin desk. The desk should fit two monitors and a laptop, so it needs to be 2m wide, which will require me to leave out three vertical supports, or at least cut them back quite a bit. The desk should be at 30-35cm height, so I can sit on a cushion on the floor in front of it (the entire room is laid out with tatami, and so far I've been working on a 30cm high table, that seems to work fine).

My current idea would be to cut the vertical boards back to 10cm width inside the cutout, and add a small, 20cm deep, bookshelf above the space that is still recessed inside the nook, so the vertical boards would look like one of these:

[image: Plan for vertical board][image: Other plan for vertical board]

This is pretty much optimal for my storage and work needs, but I don't quite trust that it will be stable enough, because the overhang will not be able to carry a lot of weight and there is no vertical stabilization in the back -- basically the entire weight of each row is carried by the front part and needs to be transferred to the back where there is a continuous connection to the floor.

Can I sensibly add horizontal supports below the bookshelf and the lowest full-length row, or will that just bend as well and not significantly take load off the weak points?

My idea here would be to fix a horizontal slat, possibly from some harder wood than the main construction, near the front to support the weak points, and anchor it on the sides (where there are no cutouts, just slots to slide in the horizontal shelves). Is that feasible?

Second, this might need stronger attachment to the wall than the original shelves (which carry all the weight on their own and just need to be kept from folding up sideways or falling over). The wall this would be up against is a load-bearing brick wall. Should I add more anchor points near the top here, and basically expect that there will be more of a pulling instead of a shearing force (so longer pegs and screws), or is that useless?

Does it make sense to switch up the wood type here for more strength (the current ones are fir/spruce) or does that introduce other issues I'm not aware of?

Should I waste a bit of space and leave 15-20cm remaining (basically, the monitors are 60cm wide, so the remaining bits on the vertical supports define how far back I can place them)?

Any other ideas I might have overlooked?

Comment: This'll work for sure with extra reinforcement as needed. You're right to not think that the shallow cutout (this is the notch for a special kind of *half-lap joint* in modern terminology, *overlap joint* in older books) will support a shelf that projects much more in front, if there will be any decent load applied (it would be fine for just a few knick-knacks though).

Comment: *"Can I sensibly add horizontal supports below the bookshelf and the lowest full-length row, or will that just bend as well and not significantly take load off the weak points?"* This will stiffen the shelf a great deal, but it won't add support where needed. You really need to add some sort of bracket underneath here, even if it is only one centrally placed.

Comment: @Graphus, I've added a variant that leaves a bit more support, although that would probably not feel as cozy, and I'm still sceptical about strength, because the shelves above sag down a bit over time.

Comment: Anything central is difficult, because I need the 200x60cm area for the monitors to be unobstructed. What I could do is something like the second variant, and then add something to strengthen along the diagonal parts.

Comment: Hmm, the nose in front probably doesn't contribute much strength anyway, so I could pretty much go in the 45 degree angle to the front

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding this in three dimensions.(eg. how many vertical members are there and what is their spacing?) An isometric sketch of the entire assembly would help a lot.

Comment: *"the shelves above sag down a bit over time"* a nosing strip of some kind (a horizontal stiffener) will help **a lot** to lessen or prevent this. So something like this is worth adding to any shelf of your current material that will see some significant weight (particularly if centrally placed and if the weight is sustained). The other options are to use thicker stock, use a stronger wood, or add a central support. *"Anything central is difficult... need.... the monitors to be unobstructed."* Metal shelf bracket? Might project downwards where the monitor sits by ~1cm.

Comment: Just as a general thing, a completely unsupported 2m span is fine if the material used is up to the expected strain. If the weight carried is more than just spaced lightweight items it's asking a lot of pine/general softwood unless the material is thicker, like a good half again as much as what you're currently using. For pine/spruce stuff to take significant weight (unsupported) it needs to be beefy, perhaps 25mm and up. Some people buy scaffolding boards as an inexpensive way of acquiring thick stock, they're a little under 40mm thick.

Comment: A quick trip to [The Sagulator](https://www.woodbin.com/calcs/sagulator/) will help you calculate the expected sag between any two vertical supports for a given load.